# Hold and Unhold sip call using the PJSIP

Tags: android, pjsip

I developing VOIP android application that make and receive the sip call.I Build the pjsip lilbrary as described in "http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android".

**1. Hold**

```
    MainActivity.prm.setOptions(pjsua_call_flag.PJSUA_CALL_UPDATE_CONTACT
            .swigValue());
    try {
        MainActivity.currentCall.setHold(MainActivity.prm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I found this code on pjsip  documentation,but this code does not work for put a call on Hold.There is no error message return.

**2.Unhold**

```
    MainActivity.prm = new CallOpParam(true);

    MainActivity.prm.getOpt().setFlag(1);
    try {
        MainActivity.currentCall.reinvite(MainActivity.prm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please elaborate this "does not work". Symptoms, error messages?

Comment: Are you able to receive a call before trying to put it on hold ? What SIP packets are exchanged with the SIP server ?

Comment: No I am unable to receive the call in an  application,I just call from application to sip number which are configured on mobile  and receive in device(not in application).Is it necessary to receive the sip call in an application for put call in hold?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for hold and unHold:

```
public void setHold(boolean hold) {
    if ((localHold && hold) || (!localHold && !hold)) return;
    if(currentCall == null) return;

    CallOpParam param = new CallOpParam(true);

    try {
        if (hold) {
            currentCall.setHold(param);
            localHold = true;
        } else {
            CallSetting opt = param.getOpt();
            opt.setAudioCount(1);
            opt.setVideoCount(0);
            opt.setFlag(pjsua_call_flag.PJSUA_CALL_UNHOLD.swigValue());
            currentCall.reinvite(param);
            localHold = false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

I hope it's helpful.